# What is the proper way to cross-reference a section within the same document?

Tags: citation

I'm updating a user manual which references other sections within the same document. Currently the cross references look like this:

> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see "Formigulating the whatzit").

I want to add page numbers and had thought about wrapping the page in parentheses, but I don't like nesting the parentheses because it just looks bad:

> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see "Formigulating the whatzit" (page 22)).

I also tried a comma. I learned years ago that a comma always goes before a quotation mark and never after one, but tried both ways and neither one looks quite "right":

> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see "Formigulating the whatzit," page 22).
>
> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see "Formigulating the whatzit", page 22).

I've also thought about italicizing the section name instead of quoting it:

> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see *Formigulating the whatzit*, page 22).

This last one looks the best out of the options thus far, but I'm wondering if there's a more technically correct solution. I tried searching for MLA style guide recommendations, but all I could find were references on how to cite external sources.

Is there a technically-correct way to cross-reference a different section and page within the same document, and if so, what is the format?

Comment: RE: _I learned years ago that a comma always goes before a quotation mark and never after one_ - "never" is such a strong word, especially on a shrinking planet. Anyhow, I'm guessing you attended school in the [United States](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/quotation-marks-with-periods-and-commas).

Comment: I think this question is probably better-suited for http://writers.stackexchange.com, where style-guide-based questions are explicitly [on-topic](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writers-se-on-topic-summary); here they are generally considered [off-topic](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here).  (I know you said you couldn't find it in MLA, but the question could be considered "is there a style guide that addresses this, and if so, what does it say?".)

Comment: @J.R. Is it that obvious? So is it standard practice to put the comma after a quotation mark outside the US if it logically makes more sense?

Comment: @Hellion My apologies; I didn't know about Writers.SE. Thanks for the info. If this question is a better fit over there and someone is able to migrate it I'd appreciate it; otherwise I can try reposting it there.

Comment: Whether to use punctuation inside or outside quotation marks is a matter of style. I learned that if the punctuation is part of the quoted material, to put it inside the quotation marks, otherwise to put it outside. This is, I believe, the style of the SCOTUS.

Comment: @rob it's not a problem, especially when one considers (a) the plethora of SE possibilities and (b) the amount of potential overlap between "English" and "Writing (in english)".  :-)  Indeed, the style-guide on/off-topicness has not yet been officially codified in our documentation here, so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the double parentheses and the commas by formulating it this way:

> Lorem ipsum blah blah (see "Formigulating the whatzit" on page 22).